# Implicit declaration of function, expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’

Tags: c

Compiler is giving errors as shown below. As far as I can tell the constants are declared correctly as well as my function calls. The program calculates a triangles area and perimeter and uses 5 different functions. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 program05.c:16:22: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before 'A'
 #define SIDE_1_LABEL 'A'
                      ^
program05.c:20:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘SIDE_1_LABEL’
 float getUserValue(char SIDE_1_LABEL, char SIDE_2_LABEL);
                         ^
program05.c: In function ‘main’:

…
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIDE_1_LABEL 'A'
#define SIDE_2_LABEL 'B'

void printInstructions();
float getUserValue(char SIDE_1_LABEL, char SIDE_2_LABEL);
float calculateArea(float side1, float side2);
float calculatePerimeter(float side1, float side2);
void printResults(float side1, float side2, float area, float perimeter);

int main()
{
    …
```

Comment: `float getUserValue(char SIDE_1_LABEL, char SIDE_2_LABEL);` - what is this supposed to do with these labels which expand to character literals? Give the parameters normal names.

Comment: `scanf("%f", %Universalside);` ??

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `float getUserValue(char 'A', char 'B');`. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: `side1     = getUserValue(SIDE_1_LABEL);`  needs two arguments: `float getUserValue(char SIDE_1_LABEL, char SIDE_2_LABEL);` same for side2

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

```
#define SIDE_1_LABEL 'A'
#define SIDE_2_LABEL 'B'

float getUserValue(char SIDE_1_LABEL, char SIDE_2_LABEL);
```

That is exactly the same as writing:

```
float getUserValue(char 'A', char 'B');
```

which is obviously invalid because 'A' and 'B' are not variable names.

If you weren't aware - macro expansion works as if you literally copy-pasted the macro definition everywhere the macro appears.

Comment: There are so many problems in OPs code that one should do not even bother to Answer to it.

Comment: @Michi I don't think that would be a sensible course of action.

Comment: @melpomene I am not going to be rude, but the OP clearly needs to read a good `C` book before he/she decides to start programming a code like that.

Comment: @Michi I have seen much worst code being UPVoted. At least OP is trying to be tidy. But yes, he needs to learn.

Comment: @sg7 Again, I do not wanna be rude, but If is so, than this Answer should concentrate on the whole problem rather than just to one. Even if the OP does make those changes it will still does not Fix the problems in its code.